Example of random process with independent increments and almost everywhere discontinuous variance
Could we provide any example of random process with independent increments and with existing and finite, but almost everywhere discontinuous (or at least not differentiable) variance? If not, why so?
I tried to construct compound Poisson process, but all my construction (with different types of rate function $\lambda (t)$) were almost everywhere continuous.
Would be glad to have any help
